# Flask uploaded file with LimitedStream or LengthReader is corrupt

Tags: python, flask

So I'm currently fiddling around with a Flask REST API.

What I want to achieve:

1. Upload a small zipfile to REST endpoint (10MB)
2. Create a new file on the server
3. Write uploaded file to the created file on the server

I tried the following:

```
@blueprint.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def upload()

    stream = request.stream

    f = open("file.zip", "wb")
    f.write(stream.read(stream.length))
```

I can see that the file is being created correctly, and no errors are thrown. But when I try to unzip the file, I'm not allowed to, because:

> Unable to expand "file.zip". It is in an unsupported format.

In continuation, I tried reading chunks off the stream as follows:

```
with open("file.zip", "wb") as f:
    while True: 
        chunk_size = 4096
        chunk = stream.read(chunk_size)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        f.write(chunk)
```

Still same outcome however.

Comment: Flask has support for file uploads. It might be better to start from examples in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/).